# Why doesn't drush respond to commands after install

Tags: drush

## Setup

I just followed the directions on the [drush website](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/?highlight=dependencies) for installing drush.

I performed the command `php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush`

Then attempted the next command `php drush core-status` which resulted in lots of text basically saying "Permission Denied".

So I went ahead and performed the next direction which makes the scripts executable. `chmod +x drush`

## The Problem

I then attempted `php drush core-status` again.

Now the console just sits there when I type the command. It displays nothing and never released back to prompt. I had to ctrl+c to free up the console.

## The Question

What am I doing wrong here? Are their dependencies on drush that are not listed in the install document? Is their some way to see errors that are not printed to the console?

I was using php 5.4 originally but updated to 5.5 and that did not solve the problem. CentOS 6.7.

Comment: FWIW I have the same problem in a docker environment using PHP 7 (the official Drupal docker image)

Comment: Sorry @LightGuard. I don't know what a "docker environment" is.

Comment: Well, the phar looks like it's broken. When I removed it and just went with compose, everything worked

Comment: Please tell us the version of Drush and the Drupal version of the site.

Comment: @cilefen Drupal version is irrelevant. Drush is a server level script. `Drush core-status` does not need nor should it need a Drupal install to function. I'm still building the server and have no active Drupal installs. I'm using whatever version the install tutorial is attempting to install. Probably the latest stable release as of yesterday around 6:00 p.m UTC. But I didn't write the script so couldn't tell you for sure.

Comment: I think @LightGuard is correct. I just installed composer then used composer to install drush. It worked fine. So it very possible the version installed by the normal readme is wrong.

Comment: @LightGuard Your solution with installing via composer worked for me. If you add it as an answer I can select it and get you some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of my comment the phar for drush wasn't working correctly. That very well may be fixed by now, however, I've still found installing drush via composer to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your server has the package php5-suhosin enabled. Disable it or add the following to suhosin.ini file (etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini): `suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar`

Answer (score -1):

You should be calling drush on its own, in the root of the Drupal install:

```
drush core-status
```

Comment: First, that is not what the install readme tells me to do. If I "should" be calling drush on it's own the documentation "should" tell me to call drush on it's own.
Second. I did try that and It has the exact same behavior.

Comment: Also drush does not need a drupal install to function.